# windows store app App Verifier failed

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, application-verifier

```
windows store app App Verifier failed
-------------------------------------
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   MoAppCrash
  Package Full Name:    **************
  Application Name: praid:App
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    52d3b719
  Fault Module Name:    vrfcore.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.2.9200.16384
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5010ae28
  Exception Code:   4000001f
  Exception Offset: 00003355
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 9d42
  Additional Information 2: 9d4286768e3a38f958aebc07f5606189
  Additional Information 3: dc25
  Additional Information 4: dc25a044c0907dfc8f3ef7768cf61489
```

I am trying to debug my app using app verifier and I got this error.Anybody know about this?

Comment: There should be more info.